# Passing an onPress event to a child component. React Native

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native and am making my first app (a calculator).

I don't know how to have a child component respond to an onClick action in the parent components. Specifically I have button components  which when clicked increment their value by one. Then in the main app component I have a reset button that on press I want to set all the  values to zero.

Here is my code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
 
export default function app() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.result}>
        <Text style={styles.resultText}>Your probability of winning is: </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttons}>
        <View style={styles.buttonColumn}>
          <CalcButton icon={require("./assets/peices/queen.png")} />
          <CalcButton icon={require("./assets/peices/rook.png")} />
          <CalcButton icon={require("./assets/peices/knight.png")} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonColumn}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.resetButton} onPress={() => { /*set all CalcButton component counters to 0*/ }}>
            <Text style={styles.resetButtonText}>Reset</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <CalcButton icon={require("./assets/peices/bishop.png")} />
          <CalcButton icon={require("./assets/peices/pawn.png")} />
        </View>
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </SafeAreaView >
  );
}
 
function CalcButton(props) {
  const [peiceCounter, counterIncrement] = useState(0);
 
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.peiceButton} onPress={() => counterIncrement(peiceCounter + 1)}>
      <Image
        source={props.icon}
        style={styles.peiceIcon}
      />
      <Text style={styles.counterText}>{peiceCounter}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity >
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a state on your app function

```
const [resetCounter, setResetCounter] = useState(false);
```

Pass resetCounter and setResetCounter to all CalcButton elements, like this

```
<CalcButton resetCounter={resetCounter} setResetCounter={setResetCounter} icon={require("./assets/peices/queen.png")} />
```

Now onPress reset button do this

```
onPress={() => setResetCounter(true)}
```

In CalcButton function add this before return

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if(props.resetCounter){
     counterIncrement(0)
  }
},[props])
```

Also add this line

```
onPress={() => {
   props.setResetCounter(false) //new line added
   counterIncrement(peiceCounter + 1)
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
 
export default function app() {
    
    
    const [initcalc, setInitCalc] = useState(false);
    const calcInit = () => {
        setInitCalc((prev)=>!prev)
    }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.result}>
        <Text style={styles.resultText}>Your probability of winning is: </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttons}>
        <View style={styles.buttonColumn}>
          <CalcButton icon={require("./assets/peices/queen.png")} initcalc={initclac} />
          <CalcButton icon={require("./assets/peices/rook.png")}  initcalc={initclac} />
          <CalcButton icon={require("./assets/peices/knight.png")} initcalc={initclac}  />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonColumn}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.resetButton} onPress={() =>  calcInit() }>
            <Text style={styles.resetButtonText}>Reset</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <CalcButton icon={require("./assets/peices/bishop.png")} initcalc={initclac} />
          <CalcButton icon={require("./assets/peices/pawn.png")} initcalc={initclac} />
        </View>
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </SafeAreaView >
  );
}
 
function CalcButton(props) {
  const [peiceCounter, counterIncrement] = useState(0);
  const init = ;
    
React.useEffect(()=>{
    counterIncrement(0);
},[prop.initcalc])
    
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.peiceButton} onPress={() => counterIncrement(peiceCounter + 1)}>
      <Image
        source={props.icon}
        style={styles.peiceIcon}
      />
      <Text style={styles.counterText}>{peiceCounter}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity >
  )
}
```

There may be a way to create a function to look up in the upper component and change to 0 in the lower component if the corresponding value changes.